# Android data binding error -- java.lang.RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null

Tags: android, android-databinding

Me and my teammate are working on a same project and
We both are using Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle 3.3 
I have used dataBinding in my code and everything works correctly:
gradle:

```
...
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
...
```

my_view.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout>
          ....
     </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

MyClass.java:

```
public class MyClass extends Toolbar {
    private MyViewBinding binding;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        initializeView();
    }

    private void initializeView() {
        this.binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), R.layout.my_view,this,  true);
        ...
    }
}
```

As I said everything works correctly for me but for my teammate Android Studio shows this error: `android studio java.lang.RuntimeException: view tag isn't correct on view:null`
Please guid us how can we fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate caches and restart in Android Studio?

Comment: @Darwind Still it has same error

Comment: @hosseinAmini first of all I would confirm that both of you are using the same version of Gradle. I know you wrote that you're using Gradle 3.3 but one of you might be using the wrapper, and the other one might be using the local Gradle distribution. `Preferences` `->` `Build, Execution, Deployment` `->` `Gradle`. Compare the `Project-level settings` section

Comment: @hosseinAmini + paste the whole error msg